# Wrap figure working as figure

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

I have the necessity of doing a document with wrap figure. For some time I used minipage to take side by side the figure and the text, but this doesn't work always. So i tried to use wrap figure, while the Overleaf example works, my document read the command wrap figure as figure command. Here the code

```
 % !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage[useregional=numeric]{datetime2}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{docmute}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\geometry{a4paper, top=0cm, bottom=7cm, left=2cm, right=2cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Logo2021.jpg}}
\setlength{\headheight}{110pt} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{footerhead}}

\newcommand{\logo}{\item[{\includegraphics[width=4mm, height=4mm]{logo_item.jpg}}]}
\newcommand{\titolo}[1]{\par \bigskip {\fontsize{14pt}{16pt} \selectfont #1}\par \bigskip}
\definecolor{principale}{RGB}{89, 89, 89}

%\setmainfont{Century Gothic}


\begin{document}
    \setmainfont{QTSchoolCentury}
    \color{principale}
    \raggedbottom
    
    \center{\fbox{\titolo{ \textit{LANTERNA SEMAFORICA IN ALLUMINIO} \textbf{ GIOTTO} \textit{TIPO BARI}}}}
        \par \bigskip
    \justifying
        \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4 \textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{GIOTTO_BARI1}
        \end{wrapfigure}

        \justifying
        Grazie alla continua ricerca di prodotti innovativi e rispondenti alle specifiche dei mercati più esigenti LA SEMAFORICA introduce “GIOTTO” la prima lanterna semaforica di fabbricazione italiana con corpo in alluminio e design slim. \\
        Disponibile nelle versioni 200 e 300 mm “GIOTTO” si inserisce nel contesto urbano con linee sottili ed armoniche contribuendo a dare un senso di ricercatezza ed eleganza alla vostra città unito ad una struttura robusta e durevole nel tempo. \\
    
    
    %   \begin{minipage}{0.6 \textwidth}
            
        GIOTTO OFFRE I SEGUENTI VANTAGGI:
        \begin{itemize}
            
        
        \logo   ECO compatibile rispetta l’ambiente riducendo le emissioni di CO2 derivate dalla produzione di energia elettrica 
    \logo   Design moderno e innovativo dalle linee sottili e non spigolose e dall’impatto estetico ridotto specialmente nella profondità del corpo lanterna che si presenta slim e compatta
        \logo   Completa di marcatura CE secondo EN12368:2015 con lenti colorate e lenti neutre fumé
        \logo Disponibile con tre diverse sorgenti di alimentazione sia normali che in versione dimmer per la riduzione della luminosità
        \logo Profondità massima per il corpo lanterna nel diametro 200 mm di 110 mm (140 considerando la lente semaforica) e per la lanterna diametro 300 mm 130 mm (177 considerando la lente semaforica)
        \logo Costruzione a scocca unica in profilato di alluminio eseguito per estrusione e su misura con lavorazioni mediante taglio laser.
        \logo Unica lanterna in alluminio con sportelli apribili singolarmente a 90° con doppio punto di aggancio
        \logo Equipaggiata con le ottiche a led monoblocco IP65 della serie STARLED2 che garantiscono luminosità e massima affidabilità uniti ad un elevato risparmio energetico
        
        
        
        \logo Visiere paraluce ad innesto rapido con inserti a pressione su 3 punti, installabili sia in posizione verticale che orizzontale.
        \logo Bracci di fissaggio della lanterna in alluminio con sistema antirotazione e disponibili in due misure 180 mm e la versione corta 90 mm. Fissaggio sia a vite che BAND-IT
        
        \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5cm}
                \includegraphics{GIOTTO_BARI1}
        \end{wrapfigure}
        
        \logo Semplice da installare sia in verticale che orizzontale
        \logo Costruzione antivandalo
        \logo Corpo lanterna e testata superiore e inferiore verniciata con vernici resistenti agli agenti esterni RAL è disponibile nelle configurazioni a seconda della scelta del cliente.
        \logo Disponibili tutte le mascherine simbolo
        \logo Di semplice manutenzione per gli operatori tecnici
        \logo Grado di protezione IP55
        \logo Disponibili pannelli di contrasto conformi alle normative italiane ed estere
        \logo Sistema di cablaggio interno con involucro in classe II
        \logo Personalizzabile sulla testata di chiusura inferiore della lanterna con una apposita targhetta metallica serigrafata a colori con il nome e il logo della città di appartenenza
    


\end{itemize}
%\end{minipage}
%   \begin{minipage}{0.3 \textheight}

%\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I thanks everyone who can help me!

Comment: note that yor first line comment indicates you are using xelatex, never use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xelatex (all hyphenation will be incorrect for T1 encoded fonts)

Comment: `\center{` is wrong, `\center` should never be used as a command in is the internal form for `\begin{center}` and it does not take an argument so would make the rest of the document cemtred, you correct that with `\justifying` but any use of `\justifying` is usually an indication of an earlier error, you should never need to specify that. Use `\begin{center}...\end{center}`

Comment: if you remove the problematic `\justifying` you may find that wrapfig works

Comment: Remove[\justifying] help a bit, but not complety.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to do it using paracol.  At least, without having access to your images.

While it is possible to break an item in the middle, it is easier to break between items.  If you were using enumerate instead of itemize, one can use the [resume] option from enumitem.

I also disabled a few options so I could run it with pdflatex (xelatex is too slow).

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage[useregional=numeric]{datetime2}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{docmute}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{paracol}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\geometry{a4paper, top=0cm, bottom=7cm, left=2cm, right=2cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Logo2021.jpg}}
\setlength{\headheight}{110pt} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{footerhead}}

\newcommand{\logo}{\item[{\includegraphics[width=4mm, height=4mm]{logo_item.jpg}}]}
\newcommand{\titolo}[1]{\par \bigskip {\fontsize{14pt}{16pt} \selectfont #1}\par \bigskip}
\definecolor{principale}{RGB}{89, 89, 89}

%\setmainfont{Century Gothic}


\begin{document}
    %\setmainfont{QTSchoolCentury}
    \color{principale}
    \raggedbottom
    
    \centerline{\fbox{\titolo{ \textit{LANTERNA SEMAFORICA IN ALLUMINIO} \textbf{ GIOTTO} \textit{TIPO BARI}}}}
        \par \bigskip
    \setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
      \switchcolumn
            \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image}
      \switchcolumn

        %\justifying
        Grazie alla continua ricerca di prodotti innovativi e rispondenti alle specifiche dei mercati più esigenti LA SEMAFORICA introduce “GIOTTO” la prima lanterna semaforica di fabbricazione italiana con corpo in alluminio e design slim. \\
        Disponibile nelle versioni 200 e 300 mm “GIOTTO” si inserisce nel contesto urbano con linee sottili ed armoniche contribuendo a dare un senso di ricercatezza ed eleganza alla vostra città unito ad una struttura robusta e durevole nel tempo. \\
    
    
    %   \begin{minipage}{0.6 \textwidth}
        GIOTTO OFFRE I SEGUENTI VANTAGGI:
        \begin{itemize}
                   
        \logo   ECO compatibile rispetta l’ambiente riducendo le emissioni di CO2 derivate dalla produzione di energia elettrica 
        \end{itemize}\unskip
    \end{paracol}
    \begin{itemize}
    \logo   Design moderno e innovativo dalle linee sottili e non spigolose e dall’impatto estetico ridotto specialmente nella profondità del corpo lanterna che si presenta slim e compatta
        \logo   Completa di marcatura CE secondo EN12368:2015 con lenti colorate e lenti neutre fumé
        \logo Disponibile con tre diverse sorgenti di alimentazione sia normali che in versione dimmer per la riduzione della luminosità
        \logo Profondità massima per il corpo lanterna nel diametro 200 mm di 110 mm (140 considerando la lente semaforica) e per la lanterna diametro 300 mm 130 mm (177 considerando la lente semaforica)
        \logo Costruzione a scocca unica in profilato di alluminio eseguito per estrusione e su misura con lavorazioni mediante taglio laser.
        \logo Unica lanterna in alluminio con sportelli apribili singolarmente a 90° con doppio punto di aggancio
        \logo Equipaggiata con le ottiche a led monoblocco IP65 della serie STARLED2 che garantiscono luminosità e massima affidabilità uniti ad un elevato risparmio energetico
        
        \logo Visiere paraluce ad innesto rapido con inserti a pressione su 3 punti, installabili sia in posizione verticale che orizzontale.
        \logo Bracci di fissaggio della lanterna in alluminio con sistema antirotazione e disponibili in due misure 180 mm e la versione corta 90 mm. Fissaggio sia a vite che BAND-IT
                
        \end{itemize}\unskip
        \setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-5cm}
        \begin{paracol}{2}
        \switchcolumn
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \switchcolumn
        \begin{itemize}
        
        \logo Semplice da installare sia in verticale che orizzontale
        \logo Costruzione antivandalo
        \logo Corpo lanterna e testata superiore e inferiore verniciata con vernici resistenti agli agenti esterni RAL è disponibile nelle configurazioni a seconda della scelta del cliente.
        \logo Disponibili tutte le mascherine simbolo
        
        \end{itemize}\unskip
        \end{paracol}
    \begin{itemize}
        
        \logo Di semplice manutenzione per gli operatori tecnici
        \logo Grado di protezione IP55
        \logo Disponibili pannelli di contrasto conformi alle normative italiane ed estere
        \logo Sistema di cablaggio interno con involucro in classe II
        \logo Personalizzabile sulla testata di chiusura inferiore della lanterna con una apposita targhetta metallica serigrafata a colori con il nome e il logo della città di appartenenza
    


\end{itemize}
%\end{minipage}
%   \begin{minipage}{0.3 \textheight}

%\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```